# @ContentChildren why cant I query Material Instances by Type

Tags: angular, angular-material

Why cant I query material instances ???

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a6ho6p?file=app/menu-overview-example.html)

## my *.html

```
<wMat-menu-group>

  <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu1</button>
  <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
    <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
  </mat-menu>

  ...

  <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu3">Menu3</button>
  <mat-menu #menu3="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item>Item 5</button>
    <button mat-menu-item>Item 6</button>
  </mat-menu>

</wMat-menu-group>
```

## my *.ts

```
  @ContentChildren(MatMenuTrigger) mmtQL: QueryList<MatMenuTrigger>; // nope
  @ContentChildren(MatMenu) mmtQL2: QueryList<MatMenu>; // nope
  @ContentChildren(_MatMenu) mmtQL3: QueryList<_MatMenu>; //  nope
  @ContentChild('menu3', {static: true}) mm3: MatMenu; //  works
```

The only method that works is a **NOT DYNAMIC ONE** and therefore **USELESS**.

Anyone has a hint?